# Multiple spaces when parsing info from email

Tags: php

I'm digesting a standardized email with PHP. The `$line` looks like this:

```
Visitor Name:      Joe Smith
```

and the code I'm using is:

```
    else if(preg_match("/Visitor Name:/",$line))
    list($label, $data[firstname], $data[lastname]) = split(" ",$line);
```

It works fine when `Visitor Name: Joe Smith` only had 1 space between `Name:` and `Joe`, but it typically comes in with multiple spaces.

Any help on how to get this to work with the multiple spaces?

Comment: Preg_split is essentially the new split. It makes it easier since it just throws everything in an array instead of having to use the list().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` and `preg_split` seem to accept a regular expression as the expression to split on, so:

```
preg_split("\s+",$line)
```

to split using one or more space characters as delimiters.

Since [`split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) is marked deprecated in the PHP documentation, you should use [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

Comment: Perfect. This solved it exactly. I used     `$namesplit = preg_split("/\s+/",$line);` and then used $namesplit[2] & $namesplit[3] to get the names.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/Visitor\s*Name:/", $line);
```

The `\s` stands for all kind of whitespaces, the `*` allows zero or more occurences.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
    $line = 'Visitor Name:      Joe Smith';
    $data = array();

    $linexp = explode(':', $line);
    $data['label'] = $linexp[0];
    $info = explode(' ', trim($linexp[1]));
    $data['firstname'] = $info[0];
    $data['lastname'] = $info[1];

    var_dump($data);
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  ["label"]=>
  string(12) "Visitor Name"
  ["firstname"]=>
  string(3) "Joe"
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(5) "Smith"
}
```